# BLE 5.0 security

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was wondering if there is any material improvement/difference in BLE security controls/requirements in BLE 5.0 spec as compared to BLE 4.2 spec. Could you advise? I skimmed through the BLE bits in the huge Bluetooth 5.0 core spec but that didn't help.

I am aware that there are significant security improvements in BLE 4.2 vs its predecessors BLE 4.0/4.1.

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Rick

Answer (score 1):

By comparing the Security Manager chapter (which defines the BLE pairing/bonding) in the Core specification of version 4.2 and 5, there are basically no changes at all except editorial ones.

The only feature difference is one in the algorithm to convert an LE LTK to/from a BR/EDR Link Key. The change here is one intermediate step that takes the key as input and generates an intermediate key using AES-CMAC with a fixed salt. Previously the LTK/Link Key was the key and the salt was the message (to AES-CMAC) while now the salt is the key and the LTK/Link Key is the message. This change is probably to make sure the stored key is not used for different purposes, which otherwise could be a security issue.